# Creating a new workbook and copying worksheets over

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

The problem in question centers around one workbook which contains all of my data and breakdowns spread across a ton of worksheets. I'm trying to get macros set up to copy select sheets to a new workbook. I think my biggest problem is getting the coding right for the destination workbook since the name includes a date string that changes each day. The code that I've got so far to just create the new workbook and close it is:

```
Sub NewReport()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    MyDate = Date

    Dim dateStr As String
    dateStr = Format(MyDate, "MM-DD-YY")

    Set W = Application.Workbooks.Add

    W.SaveAs Filename:="N:\PAR\" & "New Report Name" & " " & dateStr, FileFormat:=51

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    ActiveWorkbook.Close True
End Sub
```

This works and does what I want in regards to creating the new document, naming it the way it should be named, and at the end closing it. What I need help with is that middle portion for copying specific sheets from the original workbook to this new one. What I was thinking was along the lines of:

```
 With Workbooks("Original Workbook.xlsm")
            .Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")).Copy_ Before:=Workbooks("destination.xls").Sheet1
```

Or at least some type of array to get exactly what I want to copy over. The biggest sticking point is getting the destination workbook path name correct. Any advice regarding individual pieces of this little project or on the whole is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: I also need to point out that the new workbook being generated needs to be just plain old excel format (.xlsx). No macros, no security warning for automatic updating links or enabling macros, zip. Just a plain book of the sheets I tell it to put there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. I finally got it working now. Sheet names are carried over (otherwise I would have to go behind and rename them); it saves one copy to be sent and one copy to our archive folder; and the new workbooks don't get any popup about enabling macros or updating links.  The code I finally settled on (which could probably be trimmed a little) is:

```
Sub Report()

    Dim Wb1 As Workbook
    Dim dateStr As String
    Dim myDate As Date
    Dim Links As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    Set Wb1 = ActiveWorkbook

    myDate = Date

    dateStr = Format(myDate, "MM-DD-YYYY")

    Wb1.Sheets(Array("Sheet1Name", "Sheet2Name", "etc."))Copy

    With ActiveWorkbook
    Links = .LinkSources(xlExcelLinks)
    If Not IsEmpty(Links) Then
        For i = 1 To UBound(Links)
            .BreakLink Links(i), xlLinkTypeExcelLinks
        Next i
    End If

    End With

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="N:\" & "Report Name" & " " & dateStr, FileFormat:=51
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="N:\Report Archive\" & "Report Name" & " " & dateStr, FileFormat:=51

    ActiveWorkbook.Close

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Hope that'll help someone else with the same issue!

Answer (score 1):

Your copy line should be

```
Workbooks("Original Workbook.xlsm").Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")).Copy _
 Before:=W.Sheets(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make your code fully variable rather than harcoding "Orginal Workbook.xlsm" and the Sheet1 and Sheet2 names

If you use two Workbook variables then you can set the **ActiveWorbook** (ie the one currently selected in Excel) as the workbook to be copied (alternatively you can set it to a closed workbook, existing open named workbook, or the workbook that contains the code).

With a standard

```
Application.Workbooks.Add
```

you will get a new workbook with the number of sheets installed as per your default option (normnally 3 sheets)
By specifying

```
 Application.Workbooks.Add(1)
```

a new workbook is created with only one sheet

And note I disabled macros by setting EnableEvents to False but it would be unusual to have application events running when creating workbooks

Then when copying the sheet use

```
 Sheets(Array(Wb1.Sheets(1).Name, Wb1.Sheets(2).Name)).Copy 
 'rather than
 Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")).Copy
```

to avoid hardcoding the sheet names to be copied. This code will copy the two leftmoast sheets irrespective of naming

Lastly the initial single sheet is removed leaving you with a new file with only the two copied sheets inside

```
Sub NewReport()
    Dim Wb1 As Workbook
    Dim Wb2 As Workbook
    Dim dateStr As String
    Dim myDate As Date

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    Set Wb1 = ActiveWorkbook

    myDate = Date

    dateStr = Format(myDate, "MM-DD-YY")

    Set Wb2 = Application.Workbooks.Add(1)
    Wb1.Sheets(Array(Wb1.Sheets(1).Name, Wb1.Sheets(2).Name)).Copy Before:=Wb2.Sheets(1)
    Wb2.Sheets(Wb2.Sheets.Count).Delete
    Wb2.SaveAs Filename:="c:\test\" & "New Report Name" & " " & dateStr, FileFormat:=51

    Wb2.Close
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Getting an error message: This object doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: Well, now it's a new error message - it's saying it cannot put copy the worksheets because the destination doesn't have the same number of rows and columns, and that if I want to move the data then I should copy and paste it.

Comment: Jon, are you using the code above as is? It copies whole sheets so I don't understand why there would be a message about rows and columns (this is typically a range copy issue).

Comment: The only thing that I changed was the filepath for the SaveAs line. I left everything else the same to make sure I wasn't changing something incorrectly.  I've tried reading around about the error message and best I can tell is that maybe it has something to do with saving it as a .xlsx exptension instead of .xlms. Still fiddling with it but with no luck.